# compare 2 inputs from keyboard with strcmp leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I am new student in c language and I just come up with this. I code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char str[80];

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   char st1 = gets(str);

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   char st2 = gets(str);

   if(strcpy(st1,st2))
     printf("Same\n");
   else
      printf("Different\n");

  return 0;
}
```

My goal is to check if the 2 strings i enter from the keyboard are the same. I compile it and i get some warnings:

> hello.c: In function ‘main’:
>   hello.c:9:16: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> hello.c:12:16: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> hello.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected ‘char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char’
>
> hello.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char’

**Enter sth:** asd 
**Enter sth:** asd
 **Output**: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
 Segmentation Fault i saw that is an error when you want to access sth that it doesnt exist!

I search it a little here in Stackoverflow with similar questions and [here](http://discover.cs.ucsb.edu/commonerrors/error/2018.xml) but i dont understand why this code isnt working. Thank you!

Comment: First you should not assign your gets() function to a char. it should be a char*. Second you can't use strcopy() function with char. they should be char* too.

Comment: When you get warnings from the compiler, that means something is probably *wrong* with your program. You should try to fix the warnings, before even running the program (or, at least, not be surprised if it fails to do what you wanted it to when run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating an address of `char` variable as string and using `strcpy` instead of `strcmp`. This:

```
char st1 = gets(str);
char st2 = gets(str);
if(strcpy(st1,st2))
```

was meant to be:

```
char st1[255], st2[255];
scanf("%254s", st1);
scanf("%254s", st2);
if(strcmp(st1, st2) == 0)
```

Comment: Yes!! i did a mistake! i wanted to use strcmp but again i have a segmantation fault!

Comment: @Nat95: Just avoid using `gets` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(strcpy(st1,st2))
      ^
      |
    strcmp
```

`strcpy` is for string copy, not for string compare.
To remove *segmentation fault* change `char str1` to `char *str` and `char str2` to `char *str2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[80];
    char str2[80];

    printf("Enter sth: ");
    char *st1 = gets(str1);

    printf("Enter sth: ");
    char *st2 = gets(str2);

    if(!strcmp(st1,st2))
        printf("Same\n");
    else
        printf("Different\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you are still using `gets()`. Don't use it **ever**.

Comment: @YuHao; Yes you are right. `fgets` is a better option. I just modified the OP's code not to give seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

You get the compile warnings because `gets()` returns `char *`, but you declare `str1` and `str2` as `char`.

You get the segmentation fault because it should be:

```
if(strcpy(st1,st2))
```

should be used with `strcmp`, I guess it's a typo because `strcmp` is in your question's tag :)

Note: **Never** use `gets()`, you can use `fgets()` instead.

```
char *st1 = fgets(str, 80, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use `strcmp` but you using `strcpy`.

This code may help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char str1[80];
   char str2[80];

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   gets(str1);

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   gets(str2);

   if(!strcmp(str1,str2))
     printf("Same\n");
   else
      printf("Different\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char str[80];
   char str2[80];

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   //notice that gets is not safe,
   //if the line is too long (>79 char), you'll have a buffer overflow
   gets(str);

   printf("Enter sth: ");
   gets(str2);

   //strcmp instead of strcpy
   if(strcmp(str,str2) == 0)
     printf("Same\n");
   else
      printf("Different\n");

  return 0;
}
```